# Having Issues in Aggregation by month, week in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, amazon-athena

I want to count the records by year, quarter, month, week and I have written a query to do that but what's happening is my one week's records are going in another week's records and same is happening with month as well, for instance, month 5 records are going into month 6. So, is there any way to fix the records from month beginning to month end so that it is capturing only records in that particular month, and I want the same for week, quarter and year as well. Any idea on what might be the little fix/tweak that I need to make to correct this?

This is the query I have written.

```
SELECT

extract(year from date(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp_derived))) AS year,
extract(quarter from date(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp_derived))) AS quarter,
extract(month from date(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp_derived))) AS month,
extract(week from date(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp_derived))) AS week,
'MONTHLY' as period,

Region

,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as users
 FROM login as l
 INNER JOIN logfiles as f
on l.id = f.user_id
WHERE EXTRACT(year from date(from_iso8601_timestamp(timestamp_derived))) = 2022  
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
having count(7) >= 1
order by 7 desc
```

I have also attached a picture for the visibility. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Desired output is it should capture the total users count in one row for each region based on my grouping.

This is what I am getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbM0Z.png)

Desired Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmKsx.png)

Comment: Your question doesn't necessarily match what your image seems to describe - you're saying that the top 3 records for region SE should just appear as a single record?  But you have specified the "week" column as one of the groupings, so then of course it is going to give you 3 separate records (for 3 different weeks).  Can you please try and explain your problem better?  It would be useful if you'd include an actual example of how you expect the final output to appear

Comment: @Craig I have added the desired output. Can you please check?

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: Hi @Fiz, can you share the input table that corresponds to the output you get?